# WPF DataGrid default column types

Tags: wpf, datagrid, wpftoolkit, wpfdatagrid

I'm using a DataGrid to display 2 possible types of DataRow in a DataTable. One type has the column Parent = NULL and the other has Parent set to another DataRow in the same DataTable. The list of column in the DataTable is always different, so explicitly describing each column is not possible.

I want to display a UserControl in every cell of the Parent = DataRow rows, and default Text / Check boxes for the Parent = NULL rows. My first strategy is to try and set the default Column type for all automatically generated columns to be a DataGridTemplateColumn, regardless of datatype, so that I can use styles to then use either my UserControl or CheckBox or TextBox where required. How can I do this?

More importantly, though, is there a better strategy than this?

Cheers,
Dave